# Postgresql with Npgsql Search_Path setting

Tags: c#, postgresql-9.2, npgsql

I am sure that I have made a mistake somewhere. I read in different sites, that I can send SearchPath as a parameter in connection string for NpgsqlConnection. I tried that and it connects ok, but when I try to do select query on some table, it says "relation xx does not exist". I know I can use `"set search_path='schema'"` query. 
But I was wondering if I can do that by sending SearchPath with connection string or by changing some property parameter of NpgsqlConnection, because changing search_path for every query is not right for my case? Please suggest me something, because I am new to this... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting your search path to 'public, schema'  in your connection string?

I hope it helps.

Comment: public search_path works.. But i want to set a different search path. Sorry I forgot to mention that before

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm not understanding... If you use "search_path=public,schema" in your connection string, Npgsql will execute the set search_path='public,schema' command for you when it starts a new connection. You will have access to public and schema namespace.

Comment: @MehbubeArman any luck finding solution to this problem? I have tried to set searchpath = MYDESIREDSCHEMA   in connection string but getting error '42P01: relation "MyTableUsedInQuery" does not exist'

Comment: I had the same problem and setting grant fixed it for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409967/4648930